# Android extend three gridview height without scrollbar

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, height, fill

I have 3 different gridview in my layout. I want to fill them with specific values but without scroll them. I want that to be scrolled must be only the main linear layout, so if I move, I scroll everything and not the single gridview. This is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CHI?"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridSospettati"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="1" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridSospettatiCheck"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="6"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CHE COSA?"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridArmi"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="1" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridArmiCheck"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="6" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DOVE?"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridStanze"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="1" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridStanzeCheck"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="6" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the actual result:
[image]

As you can see, all 3 gridview are "cut" without the bottom values.

Comment: If you don't want the _GridView_ items to scroll independently of the larger layout then why use a scrolling layout such as _GridView_? Alternative are _GridLayout_ and _TableLayout_ and probably others. You could then wrap your _LinearLayout_ in a _ScrollView_ to scroll all the contents together.

Comment: The cells number is dinamic, so I don't want to create them into xml

Comment: Why don't you use `RecyclerView`s instead inside a `NestedScrollView` ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use one RecyclerView instead of GridLayout. But to get fast-fix your problem, you can make your GridLayout's height `wrap_content` and their parent Linear layouts height as `wrap_content` also.

So your code will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CHI?"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridSospettati"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="1" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridSospettatiCheck"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="6"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CHE COSA?"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridArmi"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="1" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridArmiCheck"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="6" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DOVE?"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridStanze"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="1" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridStanzeCheck"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="6" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: This don't help me because the first grids are always scrollable

Comment: @Simone what do you mean by first grids are always scrollable?

Comment: It means that rows of every left grids, show only the first 2 elements and then you must scroll them

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to design this layout is not optimal as `GridView` is a scrollable layout. The right way to do this is to use a `RecyclerView` as the root of the layout and design the `row_item` with a `TextView` header and 2 `TableLayout` instead of `GridView` below the header. You can add items to the `TableLayout` dynamically also.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I can't combine all controls together